# vector_search_configuration is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models._index.SearchField'> and will be ignored

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, langchain

I have a problem that is similar to one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345121/azure-openai-langchain-invalidfield-the-vector-field-content-vector-must-h).

I am running `azure-search-documents==11.4.0` The answer to the prior post suggested running `11.4.0b8` would suffice.  Do I need to go back to that version instead of using the subsequent released version?

Should I revert to an earlier version of LangChain?

Here is the code:

```
    vector_store = AzureSearch(
        azure_search_endpoint=os.getenv('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'),
        azure_search_key=os.getenv('AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY'),
        index_name=AISEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
        embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query
    )
```

Here is the top and bottom of the error message with a few bits in the middle included:

```
vector_search_configuration is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models._index.SearchField'> and will be ignored
semantic_settings is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models._index.SearchIndex'> and will be ignored
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceNotFoundError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/azuresearch.py:125, in _get_search_client(endpoint, key, index_name, semantic_configuration_name, fields, vector_search, semantic_settings, scoring_profiles, default_scoring_profile, default_fields, user_agent, cors_options)
    124 try:
--> 125     index_client.get_index(name=index_name)
    126 except ResourceNotFoundError:
    127     # Fields configuration

[snip]

ResourceNotFoundError: () No index with the name 'langchain-simple' was found in the service 'eai-s-eus-rrsandbox-aisearch-1'.
Code: 
Message: No index with the name 'langchain-simple' was found in the service 'eai-s-eus-rrsandbox-aisearch-1'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

HttpResponseError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 8
      6     print(os.environ[key])
      7     AISEARCH_INDEX_NAME = "langchain-simple"
----> 8 vector_store = AzureSearch(
      9     azure_search_endpoint=os.getenv('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'),
     10     azure_search_key=os.getenv('AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY'),
     11     index_name=AISEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
     12     embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query
     13 )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/azuresearch.py:299, in AzureSearch.__init__(self, azure_search_endpoint, azure_search_key, index_name, embedding_function, search_type, semantic_configuration_name, semantic_query_language, fields, vector_search, semantic_settings, scoring_profiles, default_scoring_profile, cors_options, **kwargs)
    297 if "user_agent" in kwargs and kwargs["user_agent"]:
    298     user_agent += " " + kwargs["user_agent"]
--> 299 self.client = _get_search_client(
    300     azure_search_endpoint,
    301     azure_search_key,
    302     index_name,
    303     semantic_configuration_name=semantic_configuration_name,
    304     fields=fields,
    305     vector_search=vector_search,
    306     semantic_settings=semantic_settings,
    307     scoring_profiles=scoring_profiles,
    308     default_scoring_profile=default_scoring_profile,
    309     default_fields=default_fields,
    310     user_agent=user_agent,
    311     cors_options=cors_options,
    312 )
    313 self.search_type = search_type
    314 self.semantic_configuration_name = semantic_configuration_name

[snip]

HttpResponseError: (InvalidRequestParameter) The request is invalid. Details: definition : The vector field 'content_vector' must have the property 'vectorSearchConfiguration' set.
Code: InvalidRequestParameter
Message: The request is invalid. Details: definition : The vector field 'content_vector' must have the property 'vectorSearchConfiguration' set.
Exception Details:  (InvalidField) The vector field 'content_vector' must have the property 'vectorSearchConfiguration' set. Parameters: definition
    Code: InvalidField
    Message: The vector field 'content_vector' must have the property 'vectorSearchConfiguration' set. Parameters: definition
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of your index.

Comment: I am following the example at https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/azuresearch

There is no index definition required in that example. 

I find that if I revert to `11.4.0b9` the code works.

Is the `langchain` example out of date?

What would I need to add to get that code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to 11.4.0b8 should work for you. I'm not sure what underlying API version v11.4.0 is using, but based on the error message quoted below, I suspect it is using the 2023-11-01 (general availability) version. This version has a change in the API structure for configuring the index schema, specifically around vector fields.

> vector_search_configuration is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models._index.SearchField'> and will be ignored

In the newer API versions (2023-10-01-Preview and 2023-11-01), we introduced the concept of a "profile" which aggregates various vector search settings under one name. This way, the field can reference one profile instead of requiring us to add a field property for every new vector feature we introduced. As a result of this API change, the old "vector_search_configuration" was deprecated and a new "vector_search_profile" was added, along with a new "profiles" object.

I suspect that the Langchain extension has not been updated for this change and expects the old "vector_search_configuration" property which doesn't exist on newer SDK releases.

More information behind this change can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-api-migration#upgrade-to-2023-11-01